# pagination slow with userdefined function and left join oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination, oracle10g

I'm trying to speed up a query (list of users around 60k rows) by using pagination and showing 60 records per page
 here is my query (oracle 10g)

```
select * 
  from ( select 
  a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
      from ( select u.username,u.userfullname,u.usercomment,u.isInner,u.isTeacher,u.isEmployer,u.deleted, 
     ps_fio(u.personid, 1) teachername, 
  ps_fio(sr.personid, 1) studentname,  
                case when u.isInner=1 then '' end Inn,  
                case when u.isStudent=1 then '' end Stud,  
                case when u.isTeacher=1 then '' end Teach from AD_Users u  
                left join fc_studentrecords sr on sr.recordid=u.studentid 
    order by u.username) a 
      where ROWNUM <= 120) 
where rnum  > 60;
```

problem is that once I put a left join to a fc_studentrecords table and try to  select  ps_fio(sr.personid, 1),use my query execution time goes to 8.5 sec,compared to  0.6 sec with just a left join and  sr.personid.

I did put 2 function based indexes on  ad_users  ps_fio(u.personid, 1) and  fc_studentrecords    ps_fio(sr.personid, 1)

fc_studentrecords table has around 80K rows

here is the code for ps_fio function (basically it displays  persons fullname  given the personid)

```
  create or replace FUNCTION PS_FIO(PerId PS_PERSONS.PERSONID%Type, FioType NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS 
    result VARCHAR2(70);
    gender_int NUMBER ;


    BEGIN
    select decode(m.message_id,'SEX_MALE',1,0) into gender_int
    from ps_persons p
    join rb_messages m on m.message_value=p.sex
    where personid=PerId;  

    BEGIN
    select case  
    when fiotype=0 then trim(familyname)||' '||trim(firstname)||'    '||trim(secondname)
      when fiotype=1 then trim(familyname)||' '||substr(firstname, 1, 1)||'. '||substr(secondname, 1, 1)||'.'
      else '' end into result
     from ps_persons
      where personid=PerId;  
     EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found then result:= '';
     END;
    return result;
    END PS_FIO;


here are the create table scripts for ad_users  and fc_studenrecords table

  CREATE TABLE "COPYREAL"."AD_USERS" 
   (    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(25 CHAR), 
    "USERFULLNAME" VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USERCOMMENT" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR), 
    "PWD" RAW(16), 
    "PERSONID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "ISINNER" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ISTEACHER" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ISSTUDENT" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STUDENTID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "DELETED" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ISEMPLOYER" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USERCODE" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "MOBILE_NUMBER" NUMBER(10,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_AD_USERS" PRIMARY KEY ("USERNAME")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "CH_USER_PERSON" CHECK (personid is not null or isTeacher=0) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "CH_USER_STUDENT" CHECK (studentid is not null or isStudent=0) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "UK_USERCODE" UNIQUE ("USERCODE")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_USER_PERSON" FOREIGN KEY ("PERSONID")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."PS_PERSONS" ("PERSONID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_USER_STUDENT" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENTID")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS" ("RECORDID") ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;

  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."AD_USERS_FIO_IDX" ON "COPYREAL"."AD_USERS" ("COPYREAL"."PS_FIO"("PERSONID",1)) 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 167 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."IX_FK_USER_PERSON" ON "COPYREAL"."AD_USERS" ("PERSONID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."IX_FK_USER_STUDENT" ON "COPYREAL"."AD_USERS" ("STUDENTID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;






 CREATE TABLE "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS" 
   (    "RECORDID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "PERSONID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BOOKNO" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR), 
    "BOOKDATE" DATE, 
    "DIPLOMANO" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR), 
    "PLANID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DOCDATE" DATE, 
    "DOCNO" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR), 
    "DOCSUM" NUMBER(15,2), 
    "BRANCHID" NUMBER(4,0) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STATEMENTID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "DOCPRIVTYPE" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "DOCPRIVPER" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "PREVDOC" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
    "ENTERED" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
    "STUDYFORMID" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "BUDGET" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PLACE" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
    "PAID_SUM" NUMBER(15,2), 
    "FINAL_PAYMENT_DATE" DATE, 
    "PAID_BY_CAPITAL" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(25 CHAR), 
    "INDIV_STUDENTID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "CLIENT" VARCHAR2(70 CHAR), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_FC_STUDENTRECORDS" PRIMARY KEY ("RECORDID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 720896 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "UK_BOOKNO" UNIQUE ("BOOKNO")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 917504 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "UK_FC_STYDENTRECORDS" UNIQUE ("PERSONID", "PLANID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 2097152 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_FCDSTUDRECS_RBCOMMONSTFORMS" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDYFORMID")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."RB_COMMONSTUDYFORMS" ("FORMID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_STUDENTRECORDS_DEPARTMENTS" FOREIGN KEY ("BRANCHID")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."RB_DEPARTMENTS" ("CODE") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_PS_PERSONS" FOREIGN KEY ("PERSONID")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."PS_PERSONS" ("PERSONID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_FC_STUDENTREC_PL_EDUCPLANS" FOREIGN KEY ("PLANID")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."PL_EDUCPLANS" ("PLANID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_FS_STUDREC_FC_PRIVEL" FOREIGN KEY ("DOCPRIVTYPE")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."FC_PRIVILEGETYPES" ("PRIVILEGEID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_FC_STUDENTRECORDS_AD_USERS" FOREIGN KEY ("USERNAME")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."AD_USERS" ("USERNAME") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_FCSTUDRECS_ENSTATEMENTS" FOREIGN KEY ("STATEMENTID")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."EN_STATEMENTS" ("STATEMENTID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_FC_STUDREC_IP_STUDENTS" FOREIGN KEY ("INDIV_STUDENTID")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."IP_STUDENTS" ("STUDENTID") ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 3145728 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;



  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS_FIO_IDX" ON "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS" ("COPYREAL"."PS_FIO"("PERSONID",1)) 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 167 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS_FIO_IDX2" ON "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS" ("COPYREAL"."PS_FIO"("PERSONID",0)) 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 167 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."IX_FC_STUDENTRECORDS" ON "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS" ("PERSONID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 2097152 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."IX_FK_FCDSTUDRECS_RBCOMMONSTFO" ON "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS" ("STUDYFORMID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."IX_FK_FCSTUDRECS_ENSTATEMENTS" ON "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS" ("STATEMENTID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."IX_FK_FC_STUDENTREC_PL_EDUCPLA" ON "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS" ("PLANID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."IX_FK_FS_STUDREC_FC_PRIVEL" ON "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS" ("DOCPRIVTYPE") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;


  CREATE INDEX "COPYREAL"."IX_FK_STUDENTRECORDS_DEPARTMEN" ON "COPYREAL"."FC_STUDENTRECORDS" ("BRANCHID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

here is the autotrace output from sql developer

```
buffer is not pinned count  207278
bytes received via SQL*Net from client  880
bytes sent via SQL*Net to client    20975
calls to get snapshot scn: kcmgss   207199
consistent gets 674851
consistent gets - examination   310692
consistent gets from cache  674851
CPU used by this session    890
CPU used when call started  898
cursor authentications  4
DB time 914
enqueue releases    5
enqueue requests    5
execute count   103599
index fetch by key  103590
no work - consistent read gets  260481
opened cursors cumulative   7
OS Block input operations   872
OS Involuntary context switches 62
OS Page faults  2
OS Page reclaims    1714
OS System time used 159
OS User time used   739
OS Voluntary context switches   39
parse count (hard)  5
parse count (total) 7
parse time cpu  1
parse time elapsed  1
recursive calls 103634
recursive cpu usage 687
rows fetched via callback   103512
session logical reads   674851
session pga memory  -327680
shared hash latch upgrades - no wait    78
sorts (memory)  3
sorts (rows)    53897
sql area evicted    1
SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client   9
table fetch by rowid    103600
table fetch continued row   78
table scan blocks gotten    260393
table scan rows gotten  1948362
table scans (short tables)  51797
user calls  11
workarea executions - optimal   7
```

[image: explain plan output]

[image: autotrace output]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling an PL/SQL function from inside a SQL query can be quite expensive, as it causes a switch from SQL to PL/SQL for each row.

`ad_users.person_id` seems to be nullable? I'd exclude calls to `ps_fio` if `u.personid` or `sr.personid` is `NULL`, depending on the frequency of those nulls.

Next, I'd remove the calculation of `gender_int` from the function `ps_fio` as it seems not to be used.

Next, I'd try to replace the function call with a join to the table `persons` and compute the full name directly in the query. Ugly, but may be faster.

Lastly, your calls to `trim(familyname)` etc suggest that there are trailing and/or leading spaces in the name columns of table ps_persons. The speed benefit would be minimal, but may be this clean up could be done in the table once, so that the trim function calls are not neccessary?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `HASH JOIN` on a two `FULL TABLE SCANS` execution plan, this is **no good choice for pagination**.

Why? The smaller table must be full scanned and transformed in the hash table and the first chunk of the second table must be probed befor the first page can be shown. So you have a **time penalty before the first page**. Nobody is such patient.

You ought to have an execution plan that quickly shows the first page quickly and penalize the higher pages.

Typical you use

- index to access the driving table (to avoid sort)
- nested loop join to the inner table
- index access to the inner table

Here an example (note I use hint to enforce the required access)

```
select * 
  from ( select 
  a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
      from ( select /*+ ordered use_nl(u sr) index(u AD_Users_idx) */ u.username,u.userfullname,u.usercomment,u.isInner,u.isTeacher,u.isEmployer,u.deleted, 
--  
                case when u.isInner=1 then '' end Inn,  
                case when u.isStudent=1 then '' end Stud,  
                case when u.isTeacher=1 then '' end Teach from AD_Users u  
                left join fc_studentrecords sr on sr.recordid=u.studentid 
    order by u.username) a 
      where ROWNUM <= 120) 
where rnum  > 60;
```

Be sure, that the column `username` is indexed and **NOT NULL**able (required for the index access).
Column `recordid` must be indexed as well.

The expected execution plan is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                       |   100K|    16M|  2022K  (1)| 06:44:26 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                           |                       |   100K|    16M|  2022K  (1)| 06:44:26 |
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY                 |                       |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    VIEW                         |                       |  1000K|   150M|  2022K  (1)| 06:44:26 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                       |  1000K|   182M|  2022K  (1)| 06:44:26 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| AD_USERS              |  1000K|   169M| 19871   (1)| 00:03:59 |
|   6 |       INDEX FULL SCAN           | AD_USERS_IDX          |  1000K|       |   272   (1)| 00:00:04 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN           | FC_STUDENTRECORDS_IDX |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This plan return the first page instantly, higher pages take more time as you must traverse the index. So page 10.000 in my test setup takes few seconds. But if you are patient enough to page so far this will be no problem;)

Note that I eliminated the function calls - it would be a wise idea to call them first in the out  most query, i.e. only for the selected rows - **not for the skipped rows**.

Note also in 12g you may use the [Oracle supported pagination](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55637).